# NSDecimalNumber to UInt64 conversion issue

Tags: swift, decimal, nsdecimalnumber

I have implementation of the function that is :

```
func number(for cof: UInt8, limit: UInt64) -> UInt64 {
    let decimalResult = (1 + Decimal(cof)/255) * Decimal(limit) / 1000
    return NSDecimalNumber(decimal: decimalResult).uint64Value
}
```

After usage of this function with 0 `cof`:

```
number(for: 0, gasLimit: 21000) // Result is 21
```

But when I call function with different `cof` value.

```
number(for: 128, gasLimit: 21000) // Result is 0
```

Afer debug for 128  `cof` value.

I found out that

```
 let decimalResult = (1 + Decimal(gasPriceCoef)/255) * Decimal(gasLimit) / 1000 // Result is 31.5411764705882352941176470588235294116
```

And problem is that when I convert Decimal value to UInt64 I receive 0

Comment: I think there were some bug reports about Decimal and/or NSDecimalNumber in Swift, I'll see if I can find a reference.

Comment: Shorter examples demonstrating that there is a problem: `NSDecimalNumber(string: "31.54117647058823529").uint64Value` returns 31, but `NSDecimalNumber(string: "31.541176470588235294").uint64Value` returns 13 (!), and `NSDecimalNumber(string: "31.5411764705882352941").uint64Value` returns 0.

Comment: See https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2980 – It is marked as "Resolved" but I still can reproduce the problem with Xcode 10 / Swift 4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uint64Value` is a property of `NSNumber`, and it is not well-documented when applied to `NSDecimalNumber`.

But as far as I tested, when mantissa part exceeds the range of `UInt64`, it returns `0`. For example,  `31.5411764705882352941176470588235294116` is represented as 315411764705882352941176470588235294116×10^(-38) in `NSDecimalNumber`, and `315411764705882352941176470588235294116` is bigger than `UInt64.max`. (*1)

To avoid this behavior (*2), you can round the decimal value before converting it to `UInt64`.

```
func number(for cof: UInt8, limit: UInt64) -> UInt64 {
    var decimalResult = (1 + Decimal(cof)/255) * Decimal(limit) / 1000
    var roundedResult = Decimal()
    NSDecimalRound(&roundedResult, &decimalResult, 0, NSDecimalNumber.RoundingMode.plain)
    return NSDecimalNumber(decimal:  roundedResult).uint64Value
}
print(number(for: 128, limit: 21000)) //->32
```

---

(*1) Actual behavior seems a little bit more complicated, see the *Shorter examples* in Martin R's comment above.

(*2) This behavior definitely is a bug, once marked as RESOLVED. See also another comment of Martin R's above.

Comment: That might "explain" why `NSDecimalNumber(string: "31.541176470588235294").uint64Value` returns 13 ... (31541176470588235294 % 2^64 = **13**094432396878683678). – I wonder why the bug (see my above comment) is marked as resolved.

Comment: @MartinR, definitely the behavior described in the bug report is found in Xcode 10. It may be some sort of regression, but I'm not sure why such things may happen. Anyway, we may need to write the same bug report again.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the Decimal value is not a whole number, & unint64Value won't work with that. You could always just use primitives -

```
let result = (1 + Double(cof) / 255) * Double(limit) / 1000
return UInt64(result)
```

This returns the correct result (31) in the playground